# Having more than one mongodb as windows service in one machine?

Tags: windows, mongodb, powershell

I want to install 3 mongodb in one machine.
the aim is having a replicaset setup just in different disks...

I can install one instance with this powershell line...

```
& c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config c:\mongodb\mongodb.conf --install 
& net start mongodb
```

how can I install 3 mongodb service?
how can I set service names as mongo1, mongo2, mongo3?

Comment: Is this just for testing?

Comment: actually i was planning to use this setup in some sites which does not have high traffic but have a dedicated machine

Comment: Like many DBs, Mongodb is intended to be the only major app/service running in the OS. Each will be competing for the shared resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each instance a different [ServiceName](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/). Also used PowerShell command `Start-Service` instead of `net start` to make it more PowerShell like, since you didn't use any PowerShell. :) Make sure you also have three configuration files with non conflicting options, like different ports.

```
c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config c:\mongodb\mongodb1.conf --serviceName mongo1 --install 
c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config c:\mongodb\mongodb2.conf --serviceName mongo2 --install 
c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config c:\mongodb\mongodb3.conf --serviceName mongo3 --install 
Start-Service mongo1
Start-Service mongo2
Start-Service mongo3
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also need different config files, so the `mongod` processes are running on different ports?